# Drawing multiple holes into a polygon - nokia maps api v2

Tags: maps, nokia, here-api

I donnot know how to draw multiple wholes into a polygon with Nokia Maps API v2.

[Here is an example in Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html)

[Nokia Maps API v2#Polygon](http://api.maps.nokia.com.cn/2.1.1/apireference/symbols/nokia.maps.map.Polygon.html)

Any help would be much appreciated,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HERE Maps API doesn't support cutouts directly, so the best way to do this is to build up the annulus in parts - e.g. the bottom half and the top half in separate objects. If you ensure that the `lineWidth` property of the `Polygons` is zero then you won't get an outline.

The following creates a rectangle with a hole as shown - just increase the number of points to make a ring.

[image: Rectangle with hole]

```
// Set of initial geo coordinates to create the purple polyline
var points = [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.0),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.0),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.1),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.1),
                new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.0)
    ];

// Transparent purple polyline
map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(
    points,
    {   
        pen: {
            strokeColor: "#22CA", 
            lineWidth: 5
        }
    }
));

// Transparent green polygon with black border
map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
    [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.0),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.0),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.02),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.02)
    ],
    {
        pen: { strokeColor: "#000", lineWidth: 0 },
                brush: { color: "#2C2A" }
    }
));

map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
    [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.08),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.08),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.1),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.1)
    ],
    {
        pen: { strokeColor: "#000", lineWidth: 0 },
                brush: { color: "#2C2A" }
    }
));


map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
    [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.02),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.02, 8.02),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.02, 8.08),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0, 8.08)
    ],
    {
        pen: { strokeColor: "#000", lineWidth: 0 },
        brush: { color: "#2C2A" }
    }
));

map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
    [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.02),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.08, 8.02),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.08, 8.08),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1, 8.08)
    ],
    {
        pen: { strokeColor: "#000", lineWidth: 0 },
        brush: { color: "#2C2A" }
    }
));
```

Comment: This is a solution,but the polygon that I want to draw is complex.But Thank you very much!

Comment: For a ring, it should be possible to do it with two parts - just bisect the "hole" and join the lower half to the nearest coordinate on the outer ring - you can use [Polyline.getNearest()](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Polyline.html#topic-apiref__Polyline-getNearest-method) to find the correct coordinate. Also you don't have to use `Coordinate` either - you could use an array of lat/lngs directly